# Three.js - How to Rotate Shader Material?

Tags: three.js, fragment-shader, vertex-shader, shadermaterial

My problem is trying to get the sky to rotate on its z-axis. For example if I rotate the sky by 180 degrees the shadow from the sun light should display in the opposite direction.

The code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-cloud-c00zr?file=/src/main.js:

This is where I create the sky in the `main.js` file:

```
const createSky = () => {

  const sky = new Sky();
  sky.scale.setScalar(1000);
  sky.castShadow = true;
  return sky;
};
```

I’ve tried `rotateZ` and `sky.rotation` to no avail.

The code in the `sky.js` file:

https://codesandbox.io/s/little-microservice-7nh53?file=/src/sky.js

is a modified iteration of the original three.js sky-sun-shader:

https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_shaders_sky.html

All that I have changed is the `up` position of the sky and its geometry from `boxBuffer` to `sphereBuffer`.

I would post the code here but it but it's over 200 lines of code.

I am wondering if there is a special way to rotate this `ShaderMaterial` in `sky.js`?

Comment: Just linking to code offsite is off topic for stack overflow. Please post enough code in the question itself that it can be answered without having to look offsite.

Comment: Apologies @gman I've edited my q accordingly where I create the sky and where I think I should be rotating it. My only concern is that the sky-shaders are couple of hundred lines of code in shading language and is probably too much to post here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`sky.material.uniforms.sunPosition.value.copy( light.position );` It looks like you can use this line to have the sun move from east to west.

Here the east-west is on the x axis and north-south is on z;

```
let sunPivot = new THREE.Object3D();

//add the light to the pivot at an offset off 100 units( can be changed );
light.positions.set( -100, 0, 0); 
sunPivot.add( light );
```

in the render loop:

```
sunPivot.rotateZ( 0.005 ); //arbitrary rotation speed
light.getWorldPosition( sky.material.uniforms.sunPosition.value ); //the uniform value as target (puts the world position of the light into the sunPosition.value
```